# Can't execute FastX Toolkit on Mac

Tags: macos, unix, executable

I downloaded the FastX toolkit precomplied binaries for "MacOS X 10.5.8 (32-bit)" (http://hannonlab.cshl.edu/fastx_toolkit/download.html). However, when I cd into the directory with the tools and try to execute any of them (e.g. with any command like fastq_quality_filter -h), I get the error:

-bash: /usr/local/bin/fastq_quality_filter: cannot execute binary file

I'm not positive but it seems like it might be because the file kinds are "Unix executable" which might not be compatible with Mac (though I downloaded the binaries that were supposedly for Mac). I've tried chmod + x but the files already have execution permission so that didn't help. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

macOS 10.15 (Catalina) and newer do not support 32-bit apps. If you are on 10.15 or later, you need to either compile the toolkit yourself, or find a place to download 64-bit executables.

Comment: Interesting, though I'm on 10.14.5. Do I still need to compile it myself? If so, do you know how I'd go about doing that?